# Flask - How to serve static files with Blueprint?

Tags: python, flask

I can't serve a static file from a Blueprint using Flask. I know this has been asked many times but  feel the instructions aren't clear. Also, I haven't been able to make it work. I have the following file structure:

```
  FlaskApp
    ├──__init__.py # Let's call it OuterInit.
    └── FlaskApp
        ├──__init__.py # Let's call it InnerInit.
        ├── modulo
        │   └── main.py #My blueprint
        ├── mongo
        │   └── otherBlueprint... Still not developed.
        ├── __pycache__
        ├── resources
        ├── static
        │   ├── public
        │   │   └── SomePublicFiles...
        │   └── R
        |       └── TheFileIWant.R #I want to serve this file
        └── templates
             └── index.html #I serve this template from my Blueprint. (it works)
```

**OuterInit**:
This file just starts the service. It's like my main. Somebody told me it's a good practice.

```
from FlaskApp import app
app.run()
```

**InnerInit**: This file registers the blueprint and creates the app.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)
from FlaskApp.modulo.main import map_module
app.register_blueprint(map_module)
```

**Main.py**: Here I expose the API services of this module.

```
import os
otherImports...

static_folder = os.path.join(os.pardir, 'static')
map_module = Blueprint('map_module', __name__, static_folder=static_folder, static_url_path="/static")

@map_module.route("/map")
def map():
    return render_template("index.html")

@map_module.route("/serviceData")
def serviceData():
    r = robjects.r
    r.source("R/TheFileIWant.R")
    return "Ok."
```

I can serve the index.html file and it actually displays many dynamic elements... but I can't access the R file with rpy2. I'm sure this has to do with the blueprints because before creating the blueprint (to make the program more modular) it worked.

This is what I get when I access '`http://localhost:5000/serviceData`'

```
(flaskEnv) python_user@Pipepc:~/Documents/FlaskApp$ python __init__.py 
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
/home/python_user/Documents/flaskEnv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface/__init__.py:186: RRuntimeWarning: Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) : 
  cannot open the connection

  warnings.warn(x, RRuntimeWarning)
/home/python_user/Documents/flaskEnv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface/__init__.py:186: RRuntimeWarning: In addition: 
  warnings.warn(x, RRuntimeWarning)
/home/python_user/Documents/flaskEnv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface/__init__.py:186: RRuntimeWarning: Warning message:

  warnings.warn(x, RRuntimeWarning)
/home/python_user/Documents/flaskEnv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface/__init__.py:186: RRuntimeWarning: In file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) :
  warnings.warn(x, RRuntimeWarning)
/home/python_user/Documents/flaskEnv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface/__init__.py:186: RRuntimeWarning: 

  warnings.warn(x, RRuntimeWarning)
/home/python_user/Documents/flaskEnv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface/__init__.py:186: RRuntimeWarning:  cannot open file 'R/rmethod.R': No such file or directory

  warnings.warn(x, RRuntimeWarning)
[2017-03-24 01:36:28,320] ERROR in app: Exception on /serviceData [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/python_user/Documents/flaskEnv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/python_user/Documents/flaskEnv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/python_user/Documents/flaskEnv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/python_user/Documents/flaskEnv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/python_user/Documents/flaskEnv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/python_user/Documents/flaskEnv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/python_user/Documents/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/modulo/main.py", line 19, in serviceData
    r.source("R/rmethod.R")
  File "/home/python_user/Documents/flaskEnv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/functions.py", line 178, in __call__
    return super(SignatureTranslatedFunction, self).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/python_user/Documents/flaskEnv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/functions.py", line 106, in __call__
    res = super(Function, self).__call__(*new_args, **new_kwargs)
rpy2.rinterface.RRuntimeError: Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) : 
  cannot open the connection
```

Comment: Python provides method for getting the current module directory. Use them instead.

Comment: Could you please further explain and give a solution. I'm very new to webframeworks and serving files is not very simple with Flask.

Comment: Please learn to read the [docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/blueprints/#blueprint-resource-folder). Thanks.

Comment: I did read them but I can't make it work still...

Comment: I'm assuming that you're aware that you're passing relative path to `r.path` and you have fixed it.

Comment: I think I got your point. I passed this the project's full path to my folder and it did work: r.source("FlaskApp/static/R/rmethod.R"). Although I'm not sure this is a good practice. Why even bother with static files when you can do this? I really don't get it

Comment: > Please learn to read the [docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/blueprints/#blueprint-resource-folder). Thanks.

Comment: I believe there is no need for such rudeness. I'm not asking because I'm lazy, I'm asking because I don't get what the docs are trying to explain. This is my first time working with Python, my first time working with Flask, it's even my first time developing with any web frameworks. It's my first time working with RESTful, my first time developing a web page.... and surely my last time asking a question on StackOverflow. I can't stand the rudeness in this place, I'd rather ask in Yahoo Answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is inside your call to R:

```
@map_module.route("/serviceData")
def serviceData():
r = robjects.r
r.source("R/TheFileIWant.R")
return "Ok."
```

Change to this:

```
r.source(map_module.root_path + "/R/TheFileIWant.R)
```

Also, move the R file into the folder under the blueprints. It's not a static file at all (the definition is "served as is by the web server").